# php избирательно копирует файлы

Tags: php

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: необходимо загрузить файл на сервер. Делал все по инструкциям в интернете: форма в html с enctype, method- тут все правильно, т. к. при проверке массива $_FILES выдает правильную информацию о файле. Однако дело в следующем: как я понял из интернета, функцию copy() нельзя применять ко временным файлам; использовал move_uploaded_file(), как полагается, однако эта функция не копирует файл в нужную мне директорию (C:\intetpub\<тут папка моего сайта>), если только эта директория не "C:\Windows\Temp\", откуда я собственно и переношу файл.
Проверял права доступа на этих двух папках, они идентичны. Что делать? Папку Temp засорять не хочется. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

P.S. До этого я уже поэкспериментировал с конфигом php. Кончилось все полным сносом и повторной установкой ОС на сервере. Возможно вопрос и дико нубский, но на этот раз я не хочу рисковать.

Comment: При проверке функция просто возвращает false. Параметр 'Error' в FILES равен 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да это известная проблема для Windows OS и IIS серверов.
Решение следующее - необходимо изменить настройку в php.ini для `upload_tmp_dir`. У тебя там установлено по умолчанию `C:\WINDOWS\Temp`. Измени это значение на свою директорию. 
Подробнее в этом [комментарии](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php#86332).

Comment: Пришлось еще поразбираться, но в итоге все вышло. Большое спасибо.